# Why doesn't JSON data include special characters?

Tags: json, special-characters

Why doesn't JSON data support special characters?

If json data includes special characters, etc:`\r`,`/`,`\b`,`\t`, you must transfer them, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON supports all Unicode characters in strings. What do you mean by "transferring"?

Comment: I mean that you must replace \r  with \\r

Comment: Yes, so... ? What exactly is the problem? They are automatically escaped by JSON generator (piece of code to write JSON, out of structured data), and unescaped by parser.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters need to be escaped because JSON specification says so. For some characters reasons is simple -- for example, double-quotes need to be escaped because regular double-quote ends String value, so there would be no way to tell end marker for character in content. For linefeeds reason probably was to enforce limitation that no String value spans multiple text lines; and for other control-character to avoid "invisible characters". This is similar to escaping required by XML or CSV; all textual data formats require escaping, or prohibit use of certain characters.